# What happened to this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked

This question - [Actually dispute between Windows Forms and WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710643/actually-dispute-between-windows-forms-and-wpf) was initially rapidly closed as subjective and argumentative (and rightly so), however I had a go at "objectivising" and "de-argumentavising" the question back into a more reasonable state and it was actually re-opened!

A few hours later however a diamond mod reverted the question back to revision 1 and closed / locked it.

I'm not going to argue with the decision to close the question (I voted to re-open it but I can see why it was closed), but why revert it back to its initial revision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't really change the question just made it prettier - it was still question of the kind "What’s your favorite ______?" which according to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) is not welcome in SO.

It was locked as well because the OP had nasty habit of editing with rants.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the only thing that question was good for was gathering flags.  Besides being subjective, the same question has been asked and answered several different ways already.

Comment: It looks like locking doesn't actually disable flags though, so why not delete it?

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo: If it kept getting more flags, maybe.  I dunno.  Flag it if you want it deleted.